# The script don't inherit a native class that can manage a script - Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am a Unity beginner. Today I wanted to import a script to an Empty. When I imported it, an error popped up and said "The script don't inherit a native class that can manage a script". That happened to me for the first time. I tried methods on the internet but nothing worked. Please review my code and tell me if i need to change something. Scripts:

*Menu.cs*

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class Menu : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string menuName;
        public bool open;
    
        public void Open()
        {
            open = true;
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    
        public void Close()
        {
            open = false;
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

*MenuManager.cs*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MenuManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static MenuManager Instance;

    [SerializeField] Menu[] menus;

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    public void OpenMenu(string menuName)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < menus.Length; i++)
        {
            if(menus[i].menuName == menuName)
            {
                menus[i].Open();
            }
            else if(menus[i].open)
            {
                CloseMenu(menus[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OpenMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < menus.Length; i++)
        {
            if(menus[i].open)
            {
                CloseMenu(menus[i]);
            }
        }
        menu.Open();
    }

    public void CloseMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.Close();
    }
}
```

*Launcher.cs*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using TMPro;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Linq;

public class Launcher : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public static Launcher Instance;

    [SerializeField] TMP_InputField roomNameInputField;
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text errorText;
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text roomNameText;
    [SerializeField] Transform roomListContent;
    [SerializeField] GameObject roomListItemPrefab;
    [SerializeField] Transform playerListContent;
    [SerializeField] GameObject PlayerListItemPrefab;
    [SerializeField] GameObject startGameButton;

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connecting to Master");
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected to Master");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
    }

    public override void OnJoinedLobby()
    {
        MenuManager.Instance.OpenMenu("title");
        Debug.Log("Joined Lobby");
        PhotonNetwork.NickName = "Player " + Random.Range(0, 1000).ToString("0000");
    }

    public void CreateRoom()
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(roomNameInputField.text))
        {
            return;
        }
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomNameInputField.text);
        MenuManager.Instance.OpenMenu("loading");
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        MenuManager.Instance.OpenMenu("room");
        roomNameText.text = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.Name;

        Player[] players = PhotonNetwork.PlayerList;

        foreach(Transform child in playerListContent)
        {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < players.Count(); i++)
        {
            Instantiate(PlayerListItemPrefab, playerListContent).GetComponent<PlayerListItem>().SetUp(players[i]);
        }

        startGameButton.SetActive(PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient);
    }

    public override void OnMasterClientSwitched(Player newMasterClient)
    {
        startGameButton.SetActive(PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient);
    }

    public override void OnCreateRoomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
    {
        errorText.text = "Room Creation Failed: " + message;
        Debug.LogError("Room Creation Failed: " + message);
        MenuManager.Instance.OpenMenu("error");
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(1);
    }

    public void LeaveRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
        MenuManager.Instance.OpenMenu("loading");
    }

    public void JoinRoom(RoomInfo info)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(info.Name);
        MenuManager.Instance.OpenMenu("loading");
    }

    public override void OnLeftRoom()
    {
        MenuManager.Instance.OpenMenu("title");
    }

    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        foreach(Transform trans in roomListContent)
        {
            Destroy(trans.gameObject);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < roomList.Count; i++)
        {
            if(roomList[i].RemovedFromList)
                continue;
            Instantiate(roomListItemPrefab, roomListContent).GetComponent<RoomListItem>().SetUp(roomList[i]);
        }
    }

    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
        Instantiate(PlayerListItemPrefab, playerListContent).GetComponent<PlayerListItem>().SetUp(newPlayer);
    }
}
```

If you can't help me, I will attach the source of my Unity3D 2020.3 game. Thank you!!!

Comment: Could you show us the exact error message .. also you have multiple scripts posted ... which one is the one you have the issue with?

Comment: In general the `Menu.open` is quite redundant ;) you could simply check the `menus[i].gameObject.activeSelf` ;)

Comment: Launcher inherits from "MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks" This is not part of native Unity but photon, might this be the problem?

Comment: I have issues with Menu.cs . Same thig with others

Comment: OP states the issue is also in `Menu` .. and note that `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks` inerhits from `MonoBehaviour` so that shouldn't be an issue either ;)

Comment: Photon PUN isn't. Photon PUN is an system for Unity Networking

Comment: Please post the exact error message .. also please make sure in exactly what moment the error is shown .. by `When i imported a error popped up` do you mean while Unity is recompiling or what exactly does `import` mean here? When you say `wanted to import a script to an Empty` you mean attach the components to an empty GameObject or do you mean import the script files into an empty Project?

Comment: Do you have any compiler errors? In such case it is possible that Unity didn't recompile your newly added scripts so you can't attach them to anything yet